# Scroll a WebViewWidget inside a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to display a page that has a website on top with some scrollable items below. I would like the website itself to be scrollable (i.e. scroll around the HTML page vertically) as well as the items at the flutter level. Currently I have this which doesn't let you scroll the WebViewWidget at all, it just scrolls with the rest of the scroll items but not within the web page itself:

```dart
class MapPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MapPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MapPage> createState() => _MapPageState();
}

class _MapPageState extends State<MapPage> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Load a vertically long website that needs scrolling
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'),
      )
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> scrollItems = [];

    // TODO: How to make this not part of the scroll view?
    scrollItems.add(SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: 400,
        child: WebViewWidget(controller: controller)));

    // Generate some sample data
    var someData = [for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) i];
    for (var entry in someData) {
      scrollItems.add(Text("A number: ${entry}"));
    }

    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child:
          CustomScrollView(semanticChildCount: someData.length + 1, slivers: [
        CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
          largeTitle: Text("A page"),
        ),
        SliverSafeArea(
            top: false,
            minimum: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
            sliver: SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: CupertinoListSection(topMargin: 0, children: scrollItems),
            ))
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

My first instinct was to put the `WebViewWidget` and `CustomScrollView` in a `Column` together but that doesn't work since the `Column` has infinite height. I'd also like the `WebViewWidget` to not be fixed on the screen but scroll with the items when the scroll comes from outside the area of the `WebViewWidget`, as if the scroll gestures there just got ignored by the `CustomScrollView` and passed to the `WebViewWidget` but I couldn't find a good way to get this working. Anyone have any pointers to what I can use to get this working?